# Populating a HTML select statement with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create and populate a HTML select and option tags using JavaScript.  The text to be used within the option statements comes from an XML file.  I am able to parse the XML file problem free yet I am stuck when it comes to populating the new select box.  Despite any changes I have attempted with this code it does not work.  Does anyone have any insight on what I am doing wrong here?

My XML file:

```
<londonStreets>
    <street>Clarence Street</street>
    <street>Dundas Street</street>
    <street>King Street</street>
    <street>Queens Avenue</street>
    <street>Richmond Street</street>
    <street>Waterloo Street</street>
    <street>Wellington Street</street>
    <street>York Street</street>
</londonStreets>
```

My JavaScript that I figured would create the new select box:

```
var streetSelector=document.createElement('select');
streetSelector.setAttribute('id', 'street');
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
    var option=document.createElement('option');
    option.setAttribute('value', x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue));
    streetSelector.appendChild(option);
}
```

Comment: Good for you, using regular JavaScript :)

Comment: Did you append the streetSelector to some HTML element (body, div, etc?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not appended streetSelector to your DOM.  See this JS fiddle:

```
document.getElementById("content").appendChild(streetSelector);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cszm8/

Answer (score 1):

without seeing what x is exactly, here is a simplified options populator routine:

```
var streetSelector=document.createElement('select');
streetSelector.id='street';
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    streetSelector.appendChild(new Option( x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue));
}
```